# I am rendering my website in teams tab application but update on my website not reflecting in teams tab app

Tags: tabs, microsoft-teams

Teams tab applications not reflecting my website UI or CSS Changes

Comment: Could you please clear or delete Teams desktop cache and check it once.

Comment: Without clearing cache, is there any way automatic update?

Comment: You can append a random query parameter to the stylesheet url (for example via javascript or server side code). It will not change the css file that is being loaded, but it will prevent caching, because the browser detects a different url and will not load the cached stylesheet.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mysite/style.css?id=1234">

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it’s the issue with cache implementation for pages.
Could you please try with any of the below code.

1. Use the OutputCacheAttribute to control server and/or browser caching for specific actions or all actions in a controller. Disable for all actions in a controller:

   [OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
   public class MyController : Controller
   {
   // ...
   }
2. If you want to apply a default caching strategy to all actions in all controllers, you can add a global action filter by editing your global.asax.cs or App_Start\FilterConfig.cs file and looking for the RegisterGlobalFilters method. This method is added in the default MVC application project template.

   public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
   {
   filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute
   {
   VaryByParam = "*",
   Duration = 0,
   NoStore = true,
   });
   // the rest of your global filters here
   }

This will cause it to apply the OutputCacheAttribute specified above to every action, which will disable server and browser caching.